# General term for a datum and its metadata together?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a term that describes a datum combined with its metadata.

For instance, if I were ordering a pizza, the (compound) datum would be the order, including the size, toppings, cost, delivery address, etc. Information such as who made the pizza, how long it took to make, when it left for delivery, etc would be administrative metadata. I need a term that describes both the order and this administrative metadata together.

Comment: I think you're mistaken in thinking that *who made the pizza, how long it took to make, when it left for delivery* are examples of "metadata". Effectively, ***metadata*** is just a buzzword for ***data about data***. Which after all is just more "data", so the term that describes both is simply ***data***.

Comment: If you want a different word from "data", then probably "summary" / "array" / "assortment".

Comment: What @FumbleFingers said.

Comment: Any pizza that could have metadata is not a real pizza.

Comment: I'd call them all pizza.properties.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes metadata is just data, and yes it's buzzwordy, but in this case the distinction is important. If we call it "data" we lose the information that it's a thing, combined with information about the thing.

Comment: I like summary except that a summary of a thing is simpler than the thing itself, whereas this is more complex

Comment: After the edit is now using *datum* where its clearly the plural *data* that is meant, while the misuse of *metadata* remains.

Comment: @JonHanna I changed it to datum because I wanted to make it clear that I'm talking about a thing, not a collection of things. A pizza order, not a list of pizza orders. Maybe we can call it a "compound datum", or if you prefer an "object". If you have a better term feel free to edit.

Comment: A pizza order that was a datum would just say "pizza".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I do not believe the OP is using the term inappropriately. The library's card catalog was basically collection of metadata on individual publications. I.e., the author, copyright year, number of pages, etc. are metadata about a book, which is itself data.

Comment: I think your question would be clearer if you used @jxh's example of a book combined with its cataloging information. FWIW, I'm not aware of any widely-used librarian lingo for this concept, probably because the data and metadata are generally maintained separately and you can always generate more metadata (and more levels of metadata) even when the data is theoretically static.

Comment: Although it could be considered a misnomer, ***complete data record***.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind that the word data is included in the word, then you can use

Aggregate Data

> Aggregate data is data that is produced from the combination of various pieces of atomic data. Aggregate data often forms a new data set that provides unique information and potentially valuable meaning because of the novel data combinations within.

[from businessintelligense.com](https://businessintelligence.com/dictionary/aggregate-data/)

Comment: My only gripe with this is that I think the atomic data being aggregated usually belongs to the same domain